# How to embed a greasemonkey script when connection has timed out?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, connection-timeout

I implemented a greasemonkey script to cycle around a website to gather data and send it to my server via ajax call.

Sometimes, during each page transition, connection goes timeout, firefox shows the usual "The connection has timed out" and therefore my script cannot be executed properly.

So when it happens, how can I force the browser to refresh the page or handle this status? Can I reach this behaviour just using greasemonkey or I need something else?

Comment: You can preemptively check all page links by launching GM_xmlhttpRequest with `ontimeout` callback. Otherwise you will have to use a full-fledged add-on/extension.

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, thank you. The problem is that your solution may work, but in reality it could happen that an ajax call will return "ok there is no timeout" but once the page will start to change, right in that moment the timeout will occur despite the previous "ok" statement in the ajax call ( it's all about connection issue ). You wrote about  full-fledged add-ons, but I don't know anything about. Could you explain, please?

Comment: It's complicated. See documentation for browser addons/extensions, e.g. [webRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest).

Comment: Well I guess I have to implement some addon for FF to achieve this task. I hoped in something less complex :) never mind. Thank you!